# errors not showing upon editing/updating an article - following rails guide v5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

This problem is specific to the example tutorials mentioned in the Getting Started guide of Rails 5.1.4

Upon following [Section 5.11 [Updating Articles]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles) from the rails getting started guide, it is expected that the line containing `<% if @article.errors.any? %>` in the `app/views/articles/edit.html.erb` file will get invoked if an article with empty title or empty text are tried to be saved. Meaning, the error messages should show up.

However, the article is prevented from getting updated (as expected) but the error messages do not show up (as not expected).

Is anyone familiar with this problem from the getting started tutorials explained in Rails Guide 5.1.4 ?

---

EDIT::: Following are the controller file and the view file. I have added some `puts` statements to print to the console

The `articles_controller,rb` file:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update(valid_article_params)
    puts 'article successfully updated...'
    redirect_to @article
  else
    puts 'article could not be updated...'
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private
  def valid_article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

The `edit.html.erb` file:

```
<h1>Edit article</h1>
<%= form_with(model: @article) do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <% puts 'there are some errors here in edit.html.erb' %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h3>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% puts 'errors shown from edit.html.erb' %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Comment: can we see your form ?

Comment: Please show your view (edit.html.erb) as well as controller code

Comment: Hi @Snake and @Salil . I have added the `articles_controller.rb` file and the `edit.html.erb` file for reference. Thanks for responding to this question.

Comment: Add `<%=  @article.inspect %>` below the line `<% if @article.errors.any? %>` & share what you get?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the browser view/template. It's as if the if-block is not even being called to produce the template results in the browser. However, the terminal console does produce `puts` outputs from the if-block.

Comment: Try to add `local: true` to your form

Comment: WOW!!!!!!! Yes, that did it. `local: true`. But i don't understand why. I am new to rails. @s3tjan. Maybe you can write this as an answer.

Comment: Glad to help! I check and there is an error in the Guide. The section 5.11 is missing `local: true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `local: true` to your form as follows:

```
<%= form_with(model: @article) do |form| %>
```

To:

```
<%= form_with(model: @article, local: true) do |form| %>
```

The reason is stated in the same guide:

> by default form_with submits forms using Ajax thereby skipping full page redirects. To make this guide easier to get into we've disabled that with local: true for now.

I check and the Guide contains an error. The section 5.11 is missing `local: true`

Comment: correct.... the Guide did mention the implications of `local:true` in an earlier section. But in section 5.11, they missed the `local:true` portion. Glad you noticed it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you forgot to add **local: true**. By default, all request when using form_with is ajax. So you need to turn it off

```
form_with(model: @article, local: true)
```

Read more about form_with here [link1](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197) and [link2](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a)

Comment: i see.. Ya, that solved it. I believe the rails guide needs to be updated then. As a newbie, while i was following the snippets given in the rails guide, they didn't mention `local:true` there. Glad that you picked it up correctly.